# Binding services with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have written several services that I am glueing together using Guice. For example some abstract service A is described by these interfaces

```
Response
Request
Service
```

And the implementation is defined as

```
ResponseImpl
RequestImpl
ServiceImpl
```

**Would it be better to bind all of the above implementations to their interface in the service's module, or just the Service class itself?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you seperate contract (interface) and implementation (service-impl), you usually hand only the interfaces (api-jar) to the application-clients. So they will never see (and care about) any implementing beans.

Thus, in your client code, bind the interfaces:

```
@Provides
public Service lookup() {
   return .... whatever you need to do to access the Service
}
```